# Share view between two views react-native

Tags: video, reactjs, react-native, fullscreen

I have an app similar to facebook feed with videos in them. I'm using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) to render videos. Now to make the video fullscreen I have wrapped the  component into another component. This another component has a TouchableHightlight. Within the onPress event of TouchableHighlight, a new route is created and this.props.children is passed as props to component in the route. The new component just a  which renders {this.props.children}. But this causes the wrapped Video component to unmount and it gets reconstructed in the new view (i.e. it calls the constructor of the component again). This causes the video to load and start from initial position instead of using the same component and storing the buffered data and resuming from where it left.

Link to the demo project: https://github.com/shahankit/video-player-fullscreen

I want something similar to default player controls which comes embedded when controls prop is passed.

This methods of making component go fullscreen is taken from [react-native-lightbox](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox)

Comment: Do you have to use a route to make the change, can you use state to control if the video is fullscreen or not?

Comment: Okay I can use state but in the actual app I have the video wrapped in very complex hierarchy of views. In order to make fullscreen I have to make the view wrapping the Video component go above all the components and cover entire screen.

Comment: You can change the view to be fullscreen with CSS. { position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }. Z-index might be an issue since its not supported in react-native. If so, you might want to consider simply passing the current playback time as a prop to the new component and starting the video from there

Comment: @CharlieMartin zIndex is now supported in react-native. Simply doing the following css will not help because position: 'absolute' does absolute positioning with respect to immediate parent. Whereas my video view in deep down in view hierarchy and making fullscreen is therefore difficult with just absolute positioning.

Comment: @meteors I forgot that react-native makes View's `position: relative` by default, which causes the absolute positioning to be relative to the closest parent view. You could try overriding `position: relative` on the parent views, but a better solution is to pass all information about the current state of the video as props to the new component

Comment: Even better: Do fullscreen natively. You may have to write a custom native component, though. Not sure if there's one out there.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/170

Comment: @CharlieMartin That is actually my issue. But to do fullscreen natively I required reference to the view. Is there any way I can grab reference to the view created in JS on the native side?

Comment: You need to create a custom native view and render it with JS. Something like <MyCustomVideoPlayer />. Maybe this will help...
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html

Comment: @CharlieMartin I got hold of view on native side using findNodeHandle and RCTUIManager's viewForReactTag method on native side. I successfully moved it to global window. But the button within JS view are not working. They are not receiving touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Create View Hierarchies similar to following.

```
 - Root View(position: absolute)
   - Your old entire screen layout which small video view is inside of it.
   - Your fullscreen video view with opacity = 0 with more zIndex
```

then use onPress on small video view to switch the opacity of the fullscreen video view